# Rebuild array multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

For a project i am trying to rebuild a array that the database returned. This data is needed to populate a graph.

```
  array
0 => 
array
  'payment_method_stats_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'payment_method_id' => string '92' (length=2)
  'country_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'total' => string '2' (length=5)
  'timestamp' => string '2014-01-17 13:39:41' (length=19)
  'payment_methods_id' => string '92' (length=2)
  'definition' => string 'iDeal' (length=5)
  'month' => string 'January' (length=7)
1 => 
array
  'payment_method_stats_id' => string '49' (length=2)
  'payment_method_id' => string '92' (length=2)
  'country_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'total' => string '2' (length=5)
  'timestamp' => string '2014-02-17 13:39:41' (length=19)
  'payment_methods_id' => string '92' (length=2)
  'definition' => string 'iDeal' (length=5)
  'month' => string 'February' (length=8)
2 => 
array
  'payment_method_stats_id' => string '97' (length=2)
  'payment_method_id' => string '92' (length=2)
  'country_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'total' => string '2' (length=5)
  'timestamp' => string '2014-03-17 13:39:41' (length=19)
  'payment_methods_id' => string '92' (length=2)
  'definition' => string 'iDeal' (length=5)
  'month' => string 'March' (length=5)
3 => 
array
  'payment_method_stats_id' => string '97' (length=2)
  'payment_method_id' => string '92' (length=2)
  'country_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'total' => string '2' (length=5)
  'timestamp' => string '2014-03-17 13:39:41' (length=19)
  'payment_methods_id' => string '92' (length=2)
  'definition' => string 'Paypal' (length=5)
  'month' => string 'January' (length=5)
4 => 
array
  'payment_method_stats_id' => string '97' (length=2)
  'payment_method_id' => string '92' (length=2)
  'country_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'total' => string '2' (length=5)
  'timestamp' => string '2014-03-17 13:39:41' (length=19)
  'payment_methods_id' => string '92' (length=2)
  'definition' => string 'Visa' (length=5)
  'month' => string 'January' (length=5)
```

The database returns a array with payment methods and with the month. so ideal is returned 12 times  only with a different month.

now i need this data for a graph and i want to rebuild this array into this

```
'Januari'
  =>payment
   => values, values, values, values values,
  =>payment
   => values, values, values, values, values
```

how could i accomplish this

Comment: Is there another array with the actual individual payments for each month? Actually, in your result for 'Januari': what are the 'payments' and what are the associated 'values' that you want to list with them?

Comment: this is the actual array. each payment method has  a array for each month. so what i is a two dimensional array with each month and in the money i want all payment methods with the values. i know this is a hard one but this is because of the database

Comment: Are there any other entries for 'Januari' in the array that you show us? There are no actual values anywhere in the data you show us for 'Januari'.

Comment: yes there is more then one i didn't post the complete array because it is more then 200 arrays long

Comment: We need to see at least a few of the relevant details for 'Januari' so we know what the related fields are. For example: you used 'payment' in your required output but there is no 'payment' field in the array you have shown us. Therefore you must mean some other field or tell us how to work it out.

Comment: i edited the question i hope it helps

Comment: definition is the payment method